# JS typeOf(array) = 'object'

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, typeof

I'm confused about how JS's typeOf works.

I have an ES6 class with a property array.

When I console.log this property, it shows 'object'.

```
class Team extends Model {
  constructor(view){
    super(config.saveName + ' Team');
    this.members = [];   // Clearly an array.
  }

  addPerson(person){
    this.members.push(person);
    this.emit('personAdded', person);
  }

  removePerson(person){
    if(this.members.includes(person)){
        this.members.splice(this.members.indexOf(person),1);
        this.emit('personRemoved', person);
    }
  }

  update(newTeam){
    this.members = newTeam;
    this.emit('teamDataChanged', this.members);
  }
}

console.log(typeOf(new Team().members)); // 'object'
```

Comment: JavaScript is not strongly typed. In the end an Array in JS is also an object

Comment: Two suggestions of reading: [About object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) AND [JS Data Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Data_types)

Comment: Alright, I remember about having read about this. Hmm. Problem is I want to use AppML to display the array in html. So how can I make an array out of the object property? I know it works by making an object literal. But here I have a class instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JS everything but primitives are objects. Primitives are 
: Numbers
, Booleans
, Null
, Undefined
, String
, Symbol

The rest are objects (arrays, objects, maps, sets...)

So `typeof [] === "Object"` `typeof 123 === "number"`

Comment: hum, imho there is no type of `null`

Comment: @messerbill: Null and Undefined are both data types with a single value. The behavior of  `typeof` is relatively arbitrary though.

Comment: It’s not “that” simple/straightforward. The notable outliers are `typeof null` and `typeof function(){}`. Yes, JavaScript has these data types but `typeof` itself is not completely consistent with them.

Comment: `console.log(typeof null)` returns "object".  (which really doesn't make sense to me)

Comment: @LukStorms: There might be a reason for this, but really the typeof operator is just one big lookup table: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-typeof-operator