# Javascript typeof() operator is returning a different value to the known variable type

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects, typeof

Hey I am experiencing a strange bug when I `console.log(typeof(variable)` compared to `console.log(variable)`. 
In the console the variable is clearly an array of objects, but when I `console.log` the `typeof` it says it's an `object`.
 I am fetching from an API and then trying to render the data into react.
 I think I cannot `map` through the data as it thinks it's an object.
Any help would be really appreciated, thank you!

[image: Picture showing console output]

Below is my RenderDrink component

```
import React from 'react'

function RenderDrinks(props) {
    console.log(typeof(props.data))
    console.log(props.data)
    
  return (
        
           props.data && props.data.map(drink => {
                <>
                    <h2>{drink.strDrink}</h2>
                    <p>{drink.strGlass}</p>
                    <p>{drink.strImageSource}</p>
                    <p>{drink.strInstructions}</p>
                    {/* <p>{drink.str}</p>
                    <p>{drink.str}</p> */}
                    
                </> 
            })
        
  )
}

export default RenderDrinks
```

Below is my ApiFetch component

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import RenderDrinks from '../RenderDrinks';

const FetchApi = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const fetchDrinks = async () => {
    
   await axios.get('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v2/9973533/popular.php')
   .then((res) => {
      const allDrinks = res.data.drinks
      setData(allDrinks)
      console.log(typeof(data))
    }) 
    .catch(error => console.error(`Error: ${error}`))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDrinks()
  }, [])
    
  return (
    <>
      <RenderDrinks data={data} />
    </>
  )
}

export default FetchApi
```

Comment: `typeof []` always reports `"object"`. [typeof something return object instead of array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35055222) That's not a bug. Nor is it clear why that's a problem for you.

Comment: Javascript returns type Object even if you print typeof([])

Comment: Because an array is an object @ArsalanKhan which the OP doesn't seem to understand yet.

Comment: You're not using `typeof` for anything of consequence in your code, so what's the problem?  Read some docs for `typeof` and you'll see it's by design.  There is [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray), if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS typeOf(array) = 'object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60188585/js-typeofarray-object)

Comment: An array would have to be an object the moment you use methods on it like `.sort`.

Comment: Would you please explain the error or problem happening related to react? The typeof operator is returning object as it should (take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996871/why-does-typeof-array-with-objects-return-object-and-not-array), so that's not related to any issue. Anyways I would like if you can share a JSON of an example response or something to help me understand why you're not being able to render a simple array of objects.

Comment: @mardubbles not necessarily correct. Primitives are *not* objects but you can call methods on them: `"hello".toUpperCase()`. They are being wrapped into an object automatically (or behave as if they've been) for that to take effect. Therefore, JS already has a mechanic that doesn't require a value to be an object to call methods on it. So, that's not *the* reason arrays are objects.

Comment: Ok @VLAZ. But strings are objects in your example.

Comment: Thanks everyone that is useful but it doesn't solve my problem. My map function isn't working to render my API data. Is this because it doesn't know it's an array?

Comment: @mardubbles strings literals produce primitives. An *object* would be `new String("hello")`. Try `foo = "hello"; console.log(typeof foo); console.log(foo.toUpperCase(), typeof foo.toUpperCase())` and tell me if you get any object reported: https://jsbin.com/yamizaxifa/edit?js,console

Comment: It doesnt need to "know" its an array to use `map` - it just needs to be an array! If you're getting an error that says "cannot use map...." then its not an array

Comment: @AlexPatient "*My map function isn't working to render my API data.*" that's [a completely different problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you want to solve it, ask about that and provide relevant details.

Comment: I am not getting any more error messages in the console but nothing is rendering in React

Comment: If you don't trust what is returned by API, and if you expect array - you can easy check this by calling `Array.isArray(someProperty)`

Comment: I agree with you @VLAZ. I just also think they are all objects behind the scenes.

Comment: @mardubbles they aren't. A number like `4` is most likely going to be stored as an int "behind the scenes". Not as a number object.

Comment: I have tried this and I now definitely know its an array. I am still confused as to why my map function wont work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does typeof array with objects return "object" and not "array"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996871/why-does-typeof-array-with-objects-return-object-and-not-array)

Comment: Yes @VLAZ I was thinking a literal number like 4 probably has no reason to inherit things. But does `4.toString()` work, nope. But on String it does. The expression is the immediate Object on literal string, since a literal is by definition immutable. I kinda like Javascript weirdness tho. And a more complete language wouldnt be as fun.

Comment: @mardubbles [Calling `.toString()` on a number works fine](https://jsbin.com/rupidegivu/1/edit?js,console). The specific code `4.toString()` is syntactically invalid because a numeric literal can contain `.` (e.g. `4.2`), so that is what the interpreter expects, not using the dot as a property accessor. Thus the code `4.toString()` is read as an invalid decimal notation. However, `(4).toString()` works as the brackets make it clear that `4` is the entire numeric literal. `4..toString()` also works because `4.` is a valid numeric literal (omitted digit after the dot is treated as a zero).

Comment: Good point @VLAZ on the parenthesis on syntax.

Comment: Your “map” function doesn’t return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `array` is of type `object`

If you want to test a variable of array, you can use:

```
if (data.constructor === Array)
   console.log('it's an array');
```

You can also use isArray() to check if it's an array like this:

```
if(typeof data === 'object' &&  
Array.isArray(data)) {
    //Its an array
}
```